# How to correctly check Users status for true or false via onclick using Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Before I posted this, I was unable to find solution on stackoverflow that solve my issue.

Am trying to  check users status and alert the result to check if it will return true or false.
When I click on each user, it displays following error below

**TypeError: this.state.arr[id] is undefined**

Here is the line of code that causes the  error

```
 if (this.state.arr[id].Status == true) {
```

In **angularjs**, I can achieve it and alert the result with the code below

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {


  $scope.arr = [
    {      name: "user1", Status: false },
    {      name: "user2", Status: false},
    {      name: "user3", Status: false},
    {      name: "user4", Status: false    }
  ];



  $scope.checkIt = function(id) {
alert('ok');
    if ($scope.arr[id].Status == true) {
      $scope.arr[id].Status = false;
alert($scope.arr[id].Status);
    } else {
      $scope.arr[id].Status = true;
alert($scope.arr[id].Status);
    }
  }



});


</script>
```

**Here is how am trying to work it out with reactjs**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

class Focus extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      arr: [],
    };

  //check status for true or false

    this.checkIt = function(id) {
    alert('ok');
    if (this.state.arr[id].Status == true) {
      this.state.arr[id].Status = false;

alert(this.state.arr[id].Status = false);
    } else {
      this.state.arr[id].Status = true;
alert( this.state.arr[id].Status = true);
    }
  }


  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      arr: [
    {      name: "user1",      Status: false},
    {      name: "user2",      Status: false},
    {      name: "user3",      Status: false},
    {      name: "user4",      Status: false}
      ]
    });

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <span>
        <label>
          <ul>


            {this.state.arr.map((person, index) => (

<li key={index} onClick={() => this.checkIt(this, index)}>
                {person.name} ppp
                <br />

              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </label>
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you pass `this` as the first parameter? That might cause the issue you experience.

Comment: please how do I do it

Comment: I have also tried adding state function to all the code as per below if (this.state.arr[id].Status == true) {   and it displays  this.state.arr[id] is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@zsgomori is right, don't pass `this` as an argument to `checkIt`, the lambda you are using takes care of the correct context:

```
{this.state.arr.map((person, index) => (
<li key={index} onClick={() => this.checkIt(index)}>
   {person.name} ppp
   <br />
</li>))}
```